# how to upload x509 certification to web service

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, mtom, saaj

i need to create an authentication method using x509 certifications but the verification should be done using a JAX-WS webservice so i need to upload the user's certificate to the webservice to verify it and then give the user it's appropriate permissions

what i need to know is there a good implementation example on how to upload a file to a webservice

i've been trying to do so using SAAJ with no luck it all messy

thanks

Comment: You need to do this via an offline process, not via the channel the certificate is intended to authenticate you over.

Comment: Certificate authentication is done not by merely uploading a certificate, but by performing a handshake which involves use of certificates' private keys, which are not transferred to the other party. You need to re-check your requirements and specifications.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't very clear the certificate upload is not for authentication only it's actually done to grant the users permission on objects it's a kind of implementing property certificate the idea is to use only one certificate for each user and store all the object permissions according to the cert so I need to upload the certificate to the webservice to check whether the user has permission on a specific object or not